# Inserting an example of the last 3 post on to the homepage

Tags: posts, customization, homepage

Hi everyone I am new of here, and I was looking for this answer for a while, but I guess that I am not finding the right way to google the question.

I do not know PHP, but I know quite well html and css, and I am personalising a wordpress to put on the homepage the X amount of post to be displayed and formatted as I wish.

I found on wordpress website this example

```
<ul>
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5', 'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'post-format-aside',
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            ), 
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'post-format-image',
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            )
    ) );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' .   ( __($recent["post_title"])).'</a> </li> ';
    }
?>
</ul>
```

But all it does it is just printing links, when I want excerpt of the title, the content and if there is an image attached to the post, as well the image.

I have no idea on what kind of parameter insert, and how to define the grammar. If anyone could help it would be very much appreciated, and sorry for my ignorance.

**UPDATE**

Nothing... I thought that I understood, but no. I am completely lost in the code.

**UPDATE 2**

I am trying with the current code now:

```
query_posts('show_posts=2');

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    /*
     * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
     * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
     * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
     */
     echo '<div class="txt">';
     the_title();
     the_excerpt();
     echo '</div>';
// End the loop.
endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
```

But the parameter of posts doesn't work, and it just print all the post that I have.
I understand that the query post parameter need to be assigned to the while function. No idea how.

Comment: Excerpt of the title? What theme are you using because what you want is pretty much available in most themes. Otherwise checkout   http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Thank you. I am using http://demo.graphpaperpress.com/business/ but instructions are bad, and I am having some difficulties in making work some functionality. I am reading the class reference that you passed me, I feel overwhelmed by it.

Comment: Title+Excerpt of the content. Ok I understand that I have to use "$query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=3' );" but I have no idea on how to use it in 'the loop'. I am trying various thing I just get errors, or nothing is printed. I am completely lost.

Comment: Is this in addition to posts on your homepage, or should this be the only posts on your homepage

Comment: I wanted to put the last 3 post to be displayed on the homepage like a classic blog. So with title+content+ link to go and read the whole thing. This should be the only set of posts in the homepage, the wordpress that I have doesn't display the latest posts from the blog.

Comment: Am I correct is saying that is seems that you are talking about a static front page here. Or is this just a normal homepage. Also, just a tip, I've stumbled upon your comment accidentally. Use the `@` and then the username of the user you are targeting in situations where there are more than one commenter. This will ensure that the intended user gets a notification :-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen It is a wordpress homepage, I am writing directly into the code of "homepage.php", at the moment I am just printing the title of the post, but I need to put the content of that post. No idea on what is the code. And I feel that I cannot explain myself properly as well because I do not understand what the code is actually doing or php.

Comment: Should be home.php not homepage.php

Comment: yeah sorry it is home.php I was remembering incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can understand, you are talking about a [static front page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page) as you are referring to a template called `homepage.php`. The standard homepage uses `index.php`.

To achieve 3 latest posts, you will need to create a custom query using [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). I'm not sure which parameters you need, but feel free to read throught the given link and just add them as needed to the arguments. It also seems from comments that you have trouble swithing between php and html. You will need to check out examples in tutorials for a proper explanation. I will in my code add a basic div class to the title and excerpt. You can expand and explore this further

This is a very basic example of what you need: (*Just remember, this query defaults to query the `post` post type. If you are using custom post types, you need to set the `post_type` parameter*)

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
);
$q = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    $q->the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="title">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="excerpt">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

### EDIT

From your update, the following notes:

- Never ever use `query_posts`. It breaks page functionalities and the main query
- `show_posts` should be `showposts` and is btw depreciated. You should be using `posts_per_page`

Comment: Thank you for the help @PieterGoosen I tried your solution and it get an infinite loop and than crash my browser. I was trying something along *check update 2*

Comment: Sorry, I had a syntax error. This code is untested I must add. Writing from my tablet, so the code can be buggy

Comment: Ah don't worry I think that is the closing php... let me test again.

Comment: See my update on your update :-)

Comment: Yeah fixed the code mistakes in there, and that was the solution. Thank you very much Pieter :)

Comment: My pleasure, glad you got this fixed. Enjoy :-)